# How to perform bulk update on Master table using calculations on details table in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables which have the following schemas :

```
ShoppingCard                            ShoppingCardItems
------------                            -----------------
Id                                      Id
TFTotalPriceToPay                       Id_ShoppingCard
                                        TFTotalPrice
```

I want to write a query in T-SQL to perform a bulk update which I prefer it not to use a `for loop` to do the following for me :

Calculate `Sum` of  `TFTotalPrice` of all items of each `ShoppingCard` in the `ShoppingCardItems`   table and then `Update` the `TFTotalPriceToPay` field of each `ShoppingCard` with the result .

I tried the following code :

```
    update ShoppingCard 
    set TFTotalPriceToPay=(Select Sum(TFTotalPrice) from ShoppingCardItems)
    from ShoppingCard as sc inner join ShoppingCardItems as sci on sc.Id=sci.Id_ShoppingCard
```

but I get this error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an CTE

```
with ShoppingCardItemsTotalPrice AS
(
select Id_ShoppingCard, Sum(TFTotalPrice) as TFTotalPrice
from ShoppingCardItems
group by Id_ShoppingCard
)
update sc set sc.TFTotalPriceToPay = cte.TFTotalPrice
from ShoppingCard sc inner join ShoppingCardItemsTotalPrice cte on cte.Id_ShoppingCard = sc.Id
```